# Generalization of a class of sets

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, reference-request

In topological space, we start with open set, which serves as fundamental set. We know that union of finite disjoint open sets is the smallest set amongst any kind of unions of open sets, so we have a least upper bound (or LUB) in the form of a set. Then from this LUB, we define compact set. Compact set is obviously a very important class of sets.

In measurable space, we start with elementary set, which serves as fundamental set. We know that Lebesgue outer measure is the smallest measure amongst other outer measures (e.g. Jordan), so we have a LUB in the form of a measure. Then from this LUB, we define measurable set. Again, measurable set is obviously a very important class of sets.

By fundamental set, I mean every more advanced concepts are defined based on this set, for example: connected, compact, complete, etc in topological space, or integrable, measurable in measurable space.

My questions are:

1) Is there any formal generalized framework for this:
In a certain space, we have fundamental set. In this space, we try to cover a set by another set which satisfies a certain condition in the form of LUB which is formed from this fundamental set. Then from this LUB, we have an important class of sets.

2) Other than measurable and topological space, are there any other examples?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [For each extensive, monotone function there exists a closure operator that preserves the closed sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34894/for-each-extensive-monotone-function-there-exists-a-closure-operator-that-prese) and [The lattice of closed subsets of an algebraic closure operator is an algebraic lattice](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874779/the-lattice-of-closed-subsets-of-an-algebraic-closure-operator-is-an-algebraic-l) and [MONOTONE SET FUNCTIONS, FIXED POINTS, AND CECH CLOSURE FUNCTIONS](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3826613)

Comment: They seem to be quite advanced that I'm not able to understand at my current level (3rd year). But anyway, thank you for your references!